# How to share just jupyter notebook dashboard to someone with out letting them access code?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, data-science, jupyterhub

So, I found a demo jupyter notebook online with toggles to adjust input to the graph. I would like to share this dashboard with someone without sharing the code which runs behind it.

How do I do it? I am very new to Jupyter Dashboards deploy.

I have seen tutorials and I see there is this option "deploy" under ""File" (File->Deploy As->Local Dashboard.)

Jupyter notebook example I found online has Deploy As Local Dashboard option available here and My jupyter doesn't have that option.

[A Notebook I found online with "Deploy" as option which I don't have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vX4w.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to "deploy" dashboards, you need to install the [dashboards_bundlers](https://github.com/jupyter-incubator/dashboards_bundlers) package and enable the dashboard bundler extension for Jupyter notebook. This is a one time activity within your virtual environment / conda env.

```
pip install jupyter_dashboards_bundlers
jupyter bundlerextension enable --sys-prefix --py dashboards_bundlers
```

Note: These dashboard_bundlers is part of the Jupyter Dashboards ecosystem, which comprises of:

1. [Jupyter dashboards](https://github.com/jupyter/dashboards), for arranging your notebooks' markdown and  outputs (such as plots) in reporting/ grid layout
2. a Jupyter dashboard server to deploy your notebooks to
3. the bundler extension from above, which helps in deploying local
   notebooks easily
   Optionally, you can use ipywidgets or jupyter_declarativewidgets and make your Jupyter dashboards more non-programmer friendly, by introducing dropdown, text selection, checkbox widgets etc.

These were previously in jupyter-incubator mode, but I think they were  moved to mainstream repo earlier this year.

Comment: Thank you! I tried this. Even after that I could not run it as separate server. I have dashboard view though.